# How to parse character vector in Rmarkdown to turn chunks readable?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

Inside a chunk of a Rmarkdown document, I have a loop that generates text and plots for a vector of variables.

The result is a list, that afterward is unlisted and generates a character vector:

````r
"# Variable A \n\n```{r fig.width=12, fig.height=6} \na_plot\n``` \n\nVariable A definition... [@citation2024]. \n\n\\newpage"
````

For increased readability (using `cat()`):

````
# Variable A 

```{r fig.width=12, fig.height=6} 

a_plot

``` 

Variable A definition... [@citation2024]. 

\newpage
````

I want the chunk to be read in my document so the plot appears, and not just printed. In the chunk where this code is generated, I have the option `results = 'asis'`.

I tried several alternatives but with no success...

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you *generate* the rmarkdown character vector in a loop? If yes, why don't you emit the required section/plot/text from within the loop? In case this should not be possible: please show the loop that generates the markdown string.

Comment: I found a solution, but not optimal as I describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to this solution:

````
```{r echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,results="asis",fig.width=12, fig.height=6}
i <- 1
for (i in 1:length(vars)) {
  cat("  \n#",  vars_long[i], "  \n")
  general_plot_function(data = ds,
                         var_col_name = vars[i],
                         positive = pos_construct[i],
                         email = v,
                         html = F)
  cat("  \n")
  cat(paste0(desc_vars[i],' ', refs_vars_latex[i],'. ','  \n'))
  cat(paste0(ans_scales[i],'  \n\\newpage  \n'))
}
```
````

The `general_plot_function` is generated in a separate script.

I would prefer the have the chunk options to be also generated and then, parsed. But I was not able to do it.

The vectors `vars`, `vars_long`, `pos_construct`, `desc_vars`, `refs_vars_latex` and `ans_scale` contain respectively:

1 - name of the columns in the dataset;
2 - full name of each variable (without acronyms);
3 - if it is a positive or negative variable from the perspective of desirability (e.g., burnout -> negative construct);
4 - description/definition of the variables;
5 - bibtex reference id for the citation;
6 - answer scale of the instrument (e.g., 1 - "totally disagree" to 5 - "totally agree").

The object `v` has the email of the person to which the report will be sent.
The `html` argument is to produce the plot in html to be incorporated in the `blastula` email or if it is to be included in the pdf report.

Comment: Doesn't look bad to me. If you want dynamic chunk options, you should be able to pass vectors of `length(vars)` as options. These vectors can be computerd in previous chunks.

Comment: By the way, in my opinion you could structure the `cat`ed output better by using `sprintf` instead of the last 3 cat statements.

Comment: What would be the difference between the `cat` and `sprintf` in terms of output? By the way, do you think that it would be possible to have the chunk completely generated using the `paste0` or `cat` or `sprintf ` functions?

Comment: Regarding `cat` vs. `sprintf`: No difference in terms of output. I just think that `cat(paste0(desc_vars[i],' ', refs_vars_latex[i],'. ','  \n'))` is harder to read than `cat(sprintf("%s %s. \n", desc_vars[i], refs_vars_latex[i]))` - but that's just my personal taste. Regarding generating the chunks: Yes, this should be possible. E.g., [`read_chunk`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/read-chunk.html) could be used to read a (generated) file containing chunks. However, this looks overly complex to me and your current approach is probably the way to go.